# UIButton in Swift - action is not working

Tags: ios, swift

I'm writing my first IOs app. I have my class `animation` where I register an action for my button

```
class animation {
    var view: UIView!
    init(var viewLink:UIView) {
      self.view = viewLink
      let buttonNext   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
      buttonNext.frame = CGRectMake(200, 250, 100, 50)
      buttonNext.addTarget(self, action: "nextActionButton:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
      self.view.addSubview(buttonNext)
    }
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {
      private var animClass: animation?

      required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
      }

      override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         animClass = animation(viewLink: self.view) 
      }

      func nextActionButton(sender:UIButton!) {
         println('rrr')
      }
}
```

I have an error:
`NSForwarding: warning: object 0x7fd820c94c00 of class 'animation.animation' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
Unrecognized selector -[animation.animation nextActionButton:]`

Can you help me please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: in `buttonNext.addTarget`, `self` refers to the animation class and the animation class does not have the `nextActionButton ` function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're setting the button's action to target the `animation` object where the actual method is defined in your `ViewController`.

You should pass the ViewController in to the animation's init class and use it as the target:

```
init(var viewLink:UIView, eventTarget : AnyObject) {
    ...
    buttonNext.addTarget(eventTarget, action: "nextActionButton:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    ...
}
...
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    animClass = animation(viewLink: self.view, eventTarget:self) 
    ...
}
```

Comment: @AlexandraVorobyova : Since this answer solved your problem, can you mark it as the accepted answer?